# How to get user credentials displayed as default in a WiX custom dialog

Tags: wix

I have a custom dialog that accepts user credentials and a password:

```
<Control Id="DomainNameLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="120" Width="50" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Domain" />
<Control Id="DomainNameInput" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="120" Width="250" Height="18" Property="USERDOMAIN" Indirect="no" />

<Control Id="UserNameLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="140" Width="50" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="User" />
<Control Id="UserNameInput" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="140" Width="250" Height="18" Property="USERNAME" Indirect="no" />

<Control Id="PasswordLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="160" Width="50" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Password" />
<Control Id="PasswordInput" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="160" Width="250" Height="18" Property="USERPASSWORD" Indirect="no" />

<Control Id="I360ServerName1" Type="Text" X="20" Y="180" Width="50" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="I360 Server1 Name" />
<Control Id="I360ServerName1Input" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="180" Width="250" Height="18" Property="I360SERVER1" Indirect="no" />



<Property Id="USERNAME" Value=" " />
<Property Id="USERDOMAIN" Value=" " />
<Property Id="USERPASSWORD" Value=" " />
```

I want to display the current username and domain by default values in the dialog.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know using this gets my the current user name:

```
 <Property Id="USERNAME" Secure="yes"/>
```

Use it in your control like you are and it should show the correct username, Works for me. Not sure about the domain, not using it but it may be the same..:)